# Can a 69,85 cm hp ssf proliant sit in a 800mm rack.

Tags: hp-proliant, rack, physical-environment

Hi can a hp proliant that is specified to be 69,85 cm in length fit into a 800mm closed rack. No air holes at the front of the rack. But there is a cooling unit attached to the rack. There will be a cat 6 copper LAN cable at the back and c13 plug(right angled if nessecary)

Comment: Would that be the HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8 server you mentioned earlier?

Comment: Hi @Hbruijn, It is I am a bit scared after the tight fit comment and of course the need for air intake at the front will reduce the amount of space I have at the back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know.

- What the of rack is this?
- Why is it closed?
- Are there security concerns?
- Is the server the only device in the rack?

More context is better than less...

See: [What to look for in a server rack?](https://serverfault.com/questions/470534/what-to-look-for-in-a-server-rack/470561#470561)

Don't be this guy: [Server won't physically fit in rack: which technical problems will I face in future if I force the mount?](https://serverfault.com/questions/629786/server-wont-physically-fit-in-rack-which-technical-problems-will-i-face-in-fut/629792#629792)

I tell people that modern HP servers are incredibly efficient and can run in a variety of conditions. The thermal and cooling control available in a DL380p Gen8 server is [quite comprehensive](https://serverfault.com/a/639731/13325). If you just have one, you can toss it on a shelf at normal room temperate and be fine. I wouldn't go to extremes to accommodate the server.

Comment: Hi the rack is an ip55 rack and is a requirement. The room it is in has no air conditioning so the temperature can come up to 30c. The space I have limits me to the 800mm rack.

Comment: There will be three servers in there all the same type and 2 or 3 catalyst 2960s.

Comment: And with regards to security concerns yes.

Comment: Please link to the specific rack product and description.

Comment: HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8 E5-2609 2.4GHz 4-core 1P 4GB-R P420i SFF 460W PS Entry EU   The rack is a (BxHxD) 800x2100x800, 42HE with the brackets being 650mm in Depth. Is that enough info? I dont know how to attach a file here.

Comment: Does the rack have a part number?

Comment: @ ewwhite http://www.cabinetsystem.dk/images/katalog%20cabinet%20system%202013.pdf page 25 its in danish though