# Zero-U PDU preferred mount location

Tags: electrical-power, datacenter, physical-environment, rack, power-distribution-unit

Looking for some experience from the field -

The rack I manage has two zero-U vertical PDU's supplied by the datacenter. They have fitted one on each side (one on the left, one on the right).  The rack appears designed so it can also accomodate having both PDU's mounted on one side.  In our case the vast majority of equipment has the PSU's on the left hand side, so at face value it would make more sense to have both PDU's on the left, enabling a short tidy cable run.

Is there a big downside to having both PDU's on one side, or is the choice pretty arbitrary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends... You should post the *brands* of the equipment involved.

For me, if it's a co-location facility, I'll take the lead of what the facility's staff recommend. They're the ones who need to provision power and energize the PDU's.

Also see: [What to look for in a server rack?](https://serverfault.com/questions/470534/what-to-look-for-in-a-server-rack/470561#470561)

For the datacenters I deal with, I usually mount both Zero-U PDUs on the right ride of the rack and use 1ft/2ft cables.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Curious, for one of the environments that I run, just acquired probably the same rack AR3100 and almost the same PDU (mine doesn't have monitoring). Almost the same setup of servers too ( 5 IBM X3550 M4 hosts and a 4U Supermicro chassis for ZFS storage).

What I like about APC is their accessories. In addition to your setup, I added to the left zero U cable support. Not finished the cabling yet, but soon I'll post some pictures.