# How to choose the right rack and UPS?

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, ups, rack, dell-equallogic

I have two configurations:

1. 10 Dell PE R720 servers, 2 Dell EqualLogic PS6100S arrays, 4 Dell N3000 Switches, 1 N4000 switch
2. 20 Dell PE R820, 1 Dell EqualLogic PS6100S arrays, 2 Dell N3000 Switches, 1 N4000 switch

And I'm wondering how to (wisely) choose the right rack and UPS for the hardware?

Answer (score 3):

Dell sells rebadged [APC rack and UPS equipment](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/rack-infrastructure). I tend to think APC manufacture some of the nicest racks on the market. Since your order appears to contain Dell servers, storage *and* networking, I'm sure they would be interested in providing the appropriate rack and battery. Looking at the quantity of systems, you may even have some pricing leverage.

In short, work with your Dell vendor or sales representative.

Outside of that, here's a [primer on racks](https://serverfault.com/questions/470534/what-to-look-for-in-a-server-rack/470561#470561). And the power/UPS situation is going to depend a lot on your infrastructure and facility's capabilities (e.g. Do you have a generator? What are the runtime requirements? Are you planning a dedicated circuit?)